# Joomla - 404 on Every Page, Back-End Still Works

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

all! I have a Joomla site **(http://wired-ar.com)** that I attempted an upgrade to 1.5.26 just a while ago. The upgrade went a bit awry, and I was forced to revert to a backup copy of the site using 1.5.15. Was upgrading with the intent to then upgrade to 2.x and then the latest.

I'm new to Joomla, but I believe I've reattached all the necessary components and modules. However, **I'm getting 404 errors on EVERY page.** Homepage, interior pages. I'm also having some problems with my editor, as only the top-portion of the editor appears and no TinyMCE. I've re-uploaded all editor files just to be safe, but no luck.

I haven't got a clue what's going on here, and I'm all out of leads. Most other problems like this involve the home page working, and nothing else. **On my end, the back end works a-okay, and no visual pages are coming through.** Changing different themes does not help, nor modifying any of the SEO areas, like mod_rewrite. Disabling plugins returns no results, either.

I would love some help with this, please! Any thoughts, options, or possibilities would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, and this may be the case with others, if you can access the back-end and nothing else, **you likely have a corrupted file tree that's missing components or modules**.

In my case, the **really** old files on this server had very wonky permissions, which made a smooth re-upload nearly impossible. The solution was to **check and double check all components**, adding the missing ones where needed. Took a lot of CHMOD work, too, for me.

Hope that helps someone, if you're in a similar pickle with an old Joomla site!

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable SEF url from backend, and figure out from the links, which articles/comp. are assigned to the menu. (maybe languages arent set correctly - you have assigned another lang article/category for ex. to an En lang menu)

Comment: Awesome thoughts! Thankfully, I figured it out. Full solution added here, but I really appreciate your input.